# How to access folder that is in root (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have created a folder in the root of my server. While trying to access it from a URL it gives a 404 error.

How can I create a .htaccess to access this folder and file inside the folder?

Comment: How are you accessing the foler? You said "from url", but not which protocol, which tool/application/command, and neither did you specify the operating system. You will need to provide all of those and show examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this is correct but while i change host server it is not working for only api folder

Comment: @SamyamBhandari it's not root folder?